# Java - super keyword in new thread Runnable - refers non static method thru class

Tags: java, runnable, super

In all the `super` keyword tutorials I found online, it's hard to get any examples closer to following one. 
My question:

1. What's the difference between `Tracker.super.track(event);` and `test.parent.Tracker.track(event);` ?
2. Why would the first work?
3. What does `Tracker.super` refers to? A object or a class?

subclass:

```
package test;

public class Tracker extends test.parent.Tracker {


@Override
  public void track(final Event event) {
    Executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Tracker.super.track(event);  //this works!! why??
            super.track(event); // compile error: cannot resolve
            test.parent.Tracker.track(event);  //compile error: can only reference static method
        }
    });
  }

}
```

super class

```
package test.parent;

public abstract class Tracker {

public void track(Event event) {}

}
```

**Reference Updates:**

In jls8, 15.11.2

*"Suppose that a field access expression T.super.f appears within class C, and the immediate superclass of the class denoted by T is a class whose fully qualified name is S. If f in S is accessible from C, then T.super.f is treated as if it had been the expression this.f in the body of class S. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.*

*Thus, T.super.f can access the field f that is accessible in class S, even if that field is hidden by a declaration of a field f in class T.*

*It is a compile-time error if the current class is not an inner class of class T or T itself."*

Comment: `System.out.println(Tracker.class.getName());`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What does it mean? Could you elaborate?

Comment: You are creating (and asking about) naming shadows in an anonymous local class (you're also subclassing `Runnable`). Pick whichever name you want to figure out, and print it by getting the class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No I'm not worried about the shadowing. `Tracker.super.track(event);` this runs in another thread! and track() is not a static method! So what does `Tracker.super` refers to? a class or a object?

Comment: In your `run`, a `System.out.println(Tracker.super.getClass().getName());` would have said `test.Tracker` (because `Tracker.super` refers to the enclosing instance of `test.Tracker`, the one containing the anonymous local `Runnable` and that received the `Event` in question). I'm still curious, why did you name both classes `Tracker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `run()` method is in an anonymous subclass of `Runnable` where it is also an inner class of `Tracker`.

Effectively the same as

```
package test;

public class Tracker extends test.parent.Tracker {

...
@Override
  public void track(final Event event) {
    //anonymous class translated into local class
    class TrackerRunnable implements Runnable {
      public void run(){
        Tracker.super.track(event);  //this works!! why??
        super.track(event); // compile error: cannot resolve
        test.parent.Tracker.track(event);  //compile error: can only reference static method
      }
    }

    Executor.execute(new TrackerRunnable()); 
  }
}
```

In Java an inner class also has a reference to the outer class that it "belongs" to. You would reference `this` for `TrackerRunnable` as `this` inside of run, but if you need to access the instance of `Tracker` that the `TrackerRunnable` is associated with you would access it as `Tracker.this`. Same thing with `Tracker.super`. Just `super` means the superclass of `TrackerRunnable` not `Tracker` (in this case `Runnable`).

The main thing to note is that this is syntax that is used for scope resolution only in inner classes, and that the `Tracker` here refers to "The instance of the `Tracker` class that I belong to". In the case of `test.parent.Tracker.track` `Tracker` refers to "the `Tracker` class", so you can't call instance members on the class itself.

Comment: 'Non-static inner' is a tautology,

Comment: My bad on the terminology of "static nested class" vs. "inner class". Fixed answer.

Comment: @Pshemo What EJP means is what he said, and it is stated in the JLS. I don't cite non-normative sources.